# eclipse turned folders into packages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

My Eclipse IDE suddenly changed all my folders into package names.

Normally my source is in:

```
ProjectDir >
  src >
    com.domain.projectname
```

Normally it looks like that in the Eclipse explorer window. But now it looks like this:

```
ProjectDir >
    src.com.domain.projectname
```

So it can't find my code files and resource files anymore because all the folders are added to the package name... How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the project and select configure compiler build path.  From the source folder tab make sure that the src folder is a source folder (sounds like it isn't).